# Probability for specific outcomes in fair die rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> We roll a fair die n times. We are looking for the maximum n, for which, the probability that the maximum value that appears in all outcomes is 5, is >24%.

At the beginning I thought that the probability would be $(\frac{5}{6})^n$, that is, the probability for one particular number not to be included in the outcomes (6, in our case). But then I figured out that we could have also cases where some other numbers are missing, but 5 is still the largest of those that appear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's find the total number of possibilities for the dice rolls. For every dice roll, you have 5 possibilities. This gives $5^n$ possibilities. However, you need to remove the possibility that no die is a five. There are $4^n$ possibilities of no 5 and no 6. This is out of a total number of possible ways to roll $n$ dice of $6^n$. So, the probability is:

$$\dfrac{5^n-4^n}{6^n}$$

Now, you are looking to solve:

$$\dfrac{5^n-4^n}{6^n}= .24$$

Plugging this into Wolframalpha gives about 6.27, so 6 is the maximum $n$.

Comment: Dear InterstellarProbe, can you please explain this part "However, you need to remove the possibility that no die is a five. There are..."? Thank you!

Comment: Out of all of the rolls of n dice, you want at least one die to roll a five. This gives the maximum rolled as five. So, we take all ways of rolling $n$ dice without getting a six and subtract all ways of rolling $n$ dice where we get no fives or sixes. This means that among the ways left, we have at least one die rolling a five, but no dice rolling a six.